# Displaying Conditional XML with Param and @attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML document which may or may not contain an `<errors>` node. containing any field names for which there is an error and the error notice

So an Example of this would be:

```
<errors>
    <first_name>Not allowed to be BigBoy</first_name>
    <email>Required</email>
</errors>
```

I have a FieldError Template:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldError" mode="user">
    <xsl:param name="attribute" />
    <xsl:if test="errors[@attribute=$attribute]">
        <span class="form-error"><xsl:value-of select="errors[@attribute=$attribute]" /></span>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

In my XSL file I am attempting to display the error notice next to the field name... so after each form fields I call the FieldError template thus:

After first_name field:

```
<xsl:call-template name="FieldError" mode="planner_user">
<xsl:with-param name="attribute">first_name</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>
```

After the email field:

```
<xsl:call-template name="FieldError" mode="user">
<xsl:with-param name="attribute">email</xsl:with-param></xsl:call-template>
```

I'm sure i had this working before, and I just cant see what on earth I am doing incorrectly this time

Comment: The `email` element is a child element of the `errors` element, not an attribute. So using `@` which selects attributes does not make any sense. If you want to check that a certain child element exists you would check `test="errors/*[local-name() =  $param]"` (I have changed the parameter name from `attribute` to `param` to abandon the name confusion).

Comment: Could you post a more complete example? It seems you are over-complicating this: if you know the name of the element you want to check the existence of, you could do simply `<xsl:if test="errors/email">`. If not, use a **key** to address the element dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <errors>
        <first_name>Not allowed to be BigBoy</first_name>
        <email>Required</email>
    </errors>
    <data>
        <first_name>BigBoy</first_name>
        <last_name>Smith</last_name>
        <email></email>
    </data>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="err" match="errors/*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </value>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('err', name())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="errors/*">
    <error>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </error>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <first_name>
      <value>BigBoy</value>
      <error>Not allowed to be BigBoy</error>
   </first_name>
   <last_name>
      <value>Smith</value>
   </last_name>
   <email>
      <value/>
      <error>Required</error>
   </email>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, I will have a go at implementing something along those lines.
The issue for my understanding though is that I am porting a system and the code I showed you is from another page that is working perfectly. so .I am baffled that mine wasn't

Comment: @PixelGnome It's hard to say why your code isn't working without seeing a [mcve].